# R iterate over group in R dataframe with for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, tidyverse, purrr

Need help with this. I have a dataframe with 3 columns as so.

```
date <- c(2001:2015)
countries <- c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan","Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania") 
value<- c(1:15)
df <- data.frame(date,country,value)
```

I want to apply a function `prep_plot` on each unique country and add the output together in a new dataframe. I have tried a for loop as this.

```
data <- data.frame()
for (country in unique(df$countries)){
 data1 <- prep_plot(country)
 data2 <- bind_rows(data, data1)
}
```

But the output (data2) only have data for Albania.

Comment: What does prep_plot do? Can you share that code chunk as well? If you run `prep_plot("Afghanistan")` and similarly for the first few countries, can you confirm it is returning your expected output and not nulls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `purrr`'s `map_df` :

```
result <- purrr::map_df(unique(df$countries), prep_plot)
```

Or in base R :

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(df$countries), prep_plot))
```

Comment: Lovely Ronak, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> But the output (data2) only have data for Albania.

You should replace `data2 <- bind_rows(data, data1)` with `data2 <- bind_rows(data2, data1)`. That is,

```r
data2 <- data.frame() # notice that this is changed as well
for (country in unique(df$countries)){
 data1 <- prep_plot(country)
 data2 <- bind_rows(data2, data1)
}
```

As what you where currently doing is something like `data2 <- bind_rows(data.frame(), data1)` which only gives you data for the last unique country (`"Albania"` in your case).

As other have mentioned, a solution based on `lapply` and `rbind` + `do.call` or `bind_rows` might be (much) faster (like Ronak's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66848357/5861244)).

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for pointing me to my error. It works now with your correction but i will use Ronak's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your suggestion, the following should work, no need for the data.frame even.

```r
library(dplyr)
countries %>% lapply( pred_plot ) %>% bind_rows
```

Or perhaps clearer so you know what is going on:

```
## a list of all the pred_plot outputs:

l <- lapply( countries, pred_plot ) # this applies the function to each of the countries and returns a list with all the outputs

## combine these together with rbind:
data <- bind_rows( l )
```

These statements can be chained as seen above, which a technique often turned to for simpler function calls like these, where the output of one link in the chain becomes the first argument of the function in the next, that's what the `%>%` 's is all about.